# Integral of x^p

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Can anyone explain why Mathematica does not return a conditional expression that handles the case of `p=-1` for `Integrate[x^p,x]`?
Mathematica returns `x^(1 + p)/(1 + p)`, which diverges for `p=-1`.  In order for Mathematica to return `Log[x]`, `p` must be set to `-1` before the integration.  Is there a subtle reason why this is actually correct behavior?

Comment: Well, $\lim_{p\rightarrow -1} \frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}=\ln(x)$. Not that mathematica knows this, though (try `Limit[x^(1 + p)/(1 + p), p -> -1]`)

Comment: Oh yes, I had indeed noticed that the log was not recovered in the limit.

Comment: Actually the log is recovered in the limit. It's just that mathematica doesn't recover it correctly.

Comment: @acl Don't you want $x^{p+1} - 1$ in the numerator?

Comment: Oh right that's why it doesn't work in mathematica. Oops, pattern recognised the wrong thing, I'm an idiot sorry.

Comment: Indefinite `Integrate` returns a generically correct result. For a measure zero set of values in the parameter space it might not hold. One can get a "full" result using `Integrate[t^p,{t,1,x}, Assumptions->x>1]` (and taking a limit for the special case `p->1`, per other comments).

Comment: I think the answer to this question has been given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7754414/915703).

Answer (score 5):

With **V10** one can see that the special case `p = -1` is explicitly excluded:

```
FunctionDomain[Integrate[x^p, x], p, Reals]
```

[image]

Reason: The general formula

```
Integrate[x^p, x]
```

[image]

would result in a division by zero error with `p = -1`:

```
Limit[Integrate[x^p, x], p -> -1]
```

[image]

Integrating over a certain interval one gets the expected results:

```
Integrate[x^#, x] & /@ Range[-3, 3]
```

[image]

One might want to define:

```
xpp[x_^-1] := Integrate[x^-1, x]
xpp[x_^p_] := Integrate[x^p, x]
```

Now

```
xpp[x^-1]
```

[image]

and

```
xpp[b^2]
```

[image]

**Another possibility:**

```
Assuming[p == -1, Integrate[x^p, x]]
```

[image]

```
Assuming[p != -1, Integrate[x^p, x]]
```

[image]